# pandas, renaming a multiindex column (order of data is changed)

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I do have following dataframe:

```
{'e1.data_280': {0: 10, 1: 20, 2: 30},
 'e1.data_603': {0: 7, 1: 8, 2: 9},
 'e2.data_280': {0: 30, 1: 20, 2: 10},
 'e2.data_603': {0: 8, 1: 9, 2: 1}}
```

after:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
```

it looks like:

[image]

Now I would like to get rid of the phrase `data_`:

get the three digits behind the underscore:

```
cols = [item.split('_')[1] for item in df.columns.get_level_values(1)]
cols
['603', '280', '603', '280']
```

If I replace the old labels:

```
df.columns.set_levels(cols, level=1, inplace=True)
```

The data is changed:

[image]

I see that `cols` has more entries than the name of the multiindex at level 1:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['e1', 'e2'], ['data_280', 'data_603']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0]])
```

But how can I rename the first level of multiindex columns in a dataframe ?

EDIT: A workaround

```
df.unstack().reset_index()
```

together with renaming the column and splitting the column values works:

Comment: I seem to be getting your desired results when running your code.

Comment: However I run into an error when passing `inplace=True` however the desired df is what I get without it.

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal what pandas version are you running ?

Comment: Running version 0.20.1

Comment: interesting. Me too

Comment: @piRSquared has a crazy legit answer though. Big up to that guy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'e1.data_280': {0: 10, 1: 20, 2: 30},
    'e1.data_603': {0: 7, 1: 8, 2: 9},
    'e2.data_280': {0: 30, 1: 20, 2: 10},
    'e2.data_603': {0: 8, 1: 9, 2: 1}})
```

---

**Option 1**
Easiest thing would've been to include that in your first split.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'e1.data_280': {0: 10, 1: 20, 2: 30},
    'e1.data_603': {0: 7, 1: 8, 2: 9},
    'e2.data_280': {0: 30, 1: 20, 2: 10},
    'e2.data_603': {0: 8, 1: 9, 2: 1}})

df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.data_', expand=True)

df

   e1      e2    
  280 603 280 603
0  10   7  30   8
1  20   8  20   9
2  30   9  10   1
```

---

**Option 2**
After the fact, you could do

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('data_', ''))

   e1      e2    
  280 603 280 603
0  10   7  30   8
1  20   8  20   9
2  30   9  10   1
```

You can even narrow the scope of `rename` by passing a `level`.  This ensures we don't perform the `replace` on `level=0` column objects.

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('data_', ''), level=1)

   e1      e2    
  280 603 280 603
0  10   7  30   8
1  20   8  20   9
2  30   9  10   1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cols = [item.split('_')[1] for item in df.columns.levels[1]]`; this will preserve the alignment.

Comment: Did I luck out by having the dict be in that same order when creating `cols`?

Comment: I do not believe so, but your approach should fail if two values at level 0 have different subsets of values on level 1.